# How do I automatically connect to Wifi on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, wireless, internet

I have a laptop and know nothing about terminal but I have the latest version of Ubuntu, and unlike previous versions, when you go to the Wifi in Settings you have to have an adapter, some solutions say to use the terminal to log in but I don't understand that please help me! I've tried many things, and it's just not working. And I know its not the Hardware, because when I go into BIOS and open an older version of Ubuntu it's connected. Please help! Also it shows up in nmtui "Edit a connection"

Comment: There is no actionable information here. Could you update your question to include the brand and model of your computer, and perhaps screenshots of the network settings (if you're not comfortable using terminal)? With specific details it might be possible for someone to offer a suggestion.

Comment: The network card is probably fine however you may not have the driver loaded for it. If you run the command 'inxi -n' what does it say about network cards? To open a terminal press control alt T

Comment: In your edit, please give us the details of exactly what you've tried so far and tell us the outcome of each attempt.  This could contain valuable diagnostic information.